# How can I force git to always branch from master?

Tags: git

I keep accidentally branching from the feature branch that I was last working on, rather than from master. This causes confusion in the history.

I would like to either:

- Block branching from all branches except master
- Make master the default branch to create new branches from, i.e. setting  as a default here:

  ```
  git branch [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>
  ```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You just have to systematically define the source branch when you create a new one like in `git checkout -b mynewbranch origin/master`.

Answer (score 5):

I would configure a Git alias to accomplish this.

`git config alias.braster "checkout master -b"`

To use it type (braster as in branch master):

`git braster feature1`

Comment: You could also include more commands to checkout the newest origin/master first, if you are working with a team. Creating mini scripts/aliases like this is a great skill to develop.

Answer (score 4):

Overwriting git's default operation can lead to some unexpected results when using external git tools.

I would recommend creating an alias for this purpose.

add the following line to your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias gb="git checkout master; git checkout -b"
```

or run the following command:

```
echo alias gb="git checkout master; git checkout -b" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Branches don't *have* source branches.  They are just labels, pointing to commits.  (See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))  It's the commits that really matter: A Git repository is all about commits.  What branch names do for us is that they let us *find* commits, whose real names—their hash IDs—appear to be random, and which no human can ever remember.

More specifically, a *branch name* is simply a human-readable place in which your Git stores the raw hash ID of one commit, with another special feature: if you run `git checkout <name>`, Git not only checks out that one particular commit, it *also* **remembers** that name as being your *current branch*.<sup>1</sup>  Whatever branch name is your *current* branch, when you make a *new* commit, the raw hash ID of the new commit you just made gets stuffed into that branch's name.

The result is that if you make new branch name `branch9` like this:

```
git branch branch9 a123456
```

then the name `branch9` now points to the existing commit whose hash ID is `a123456`.  The `git branch` command will take *anything* that can be turned into a raw commit hash ID.  Using:

```
git branch branch9 master
```

turns `master` into a hash ID (by reading out the hash ID stored in the name `master`) and uses that to set up the new name `branch9` to hold the *same* hash ID.

Aside from cloning the source to Git and changing it and building your own version, there's no way to change the syntax or options that `git branch` will accept here.  The same goes for `git checkout -b`, `git checkout -B`, and `git reset`, all of which can create new branches or force a raw hash ID into a branch name.

Your best bet is probably to set up your own alias (shell / CLI alias, or Git alias), as in [Rickard Körkkö's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59304672/1256452) and [gkpin3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59304323/1256452).

---

<sup>1</sup>There are additional special features for branch names, none of which apply to *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master`, but this particular one—the one that Git effectively calls an *attached HEAD*, as compared to what Git calls a *detached HEAD* anyway—is the most important by far.